# Fancy String Replace

Tags: code-golf, string

let `S`, `a` and `b` each represent a string

Goal: Write a standard string replace function where the you replace all occurrences of `a` in a string `S` with `b` so long as `a` is not already part of an instance of `b`

for example, if we have the string `S` = `My oh my that there is a big ol' that`

and we wanted to do a fancy replace with `a = that` and `b = that there` we would replace every instance of `that` with `that there` as long as the instance of `that` isn't already an instance of `that there`

So in this case the output would be: `My oh my that there is a big ol' that there`

The first `that` is not replaced because it is already part of an instance of `that there`

#### Notes

- All 3 inputs must be strings containing only printable ascii characters
- Input may be given as 3 separate strings or a list of 3 strings
- Input will be in the order `S`, `a`, `b` unless otherwise specified in the answer
- In order for `a` to be considered a part of `b`, all of the instance of `a` must be part of an instance `b`

#### Some Corner Cases Explained

```
Input:  ["1222", "22", "122"]
Output: "12122"
```

In the case above example the latter `22` is replaced. Even though part of it is part of an instance of `b`, the entirety of it is NOT a part of the instance of `b`. Since the entire instance of `a` is not part of an instance of `b` it is replaced.

```
Input:  ["123 ", "23", "12"]
Output: "112 "
```

This test case illustrates the same case as above but perhaps in a slightly more clear way. Again the `2` in the middle is both part of an instance of `a` as well as part of an instance of `b`, however since all of `a` is not part of the instance of `b` it is still replaced.

```
Input: ["Empty", "", "p"]
Output: "pEpmptpyp"
```

In the above test case both the empty string before and after the `p` are not replaced as the can wholly be considered part of the instance of `p`.

#### Other Test Cases

```
Input:  ["aabbaa", "aa", "aabb"]
Output: "aabbaabb"

Input:  ["Hello World!", "o", " no"]
Output: "Hell no W norld!"

Input: ["Wow, oh wow, seriously WOW that's... wow", "wow", "WOW,"]
Output: "Wow, oh WOW,, seriously WOW that's... WOW,"

Input: ["Empty", "", "b"]
Output: "bEbmbpbtbyb"

Input: ["Empty", "b", "br"]
Output: "Empty"

Input: ["Empty", "pty", "Empty"]
Output: "Empty"

Input:  ["aabbaaa", "aa", "PP"]
Output: "PPbbPPa"

Input:  ["121212","1","121"]
Output: "121212"
```

---

This is a question for code-golf so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97721/discussion-between-quinn-and-tsh).

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 76 bytes

```perl6
{$^b;$^a;&{S:g/$a<?{$!=$/;all m:ex/$b/>>.&{$!.to>.to||.from>$!.from}}>/$b/}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBboJAEL3zFeNmY7WhWDDpQSumB5M2aeKhSTkoNrstVhNwt4CxBPl2O4NIMdGQeTP73rzHgg7i8OEQZdBewuiQ84Uc8oUYtvO3wXePi8dxzlsj3huKMIRoEPz2uOy5rtVG2kqVi7XfW8tYRS4S1IvCpZ2iOCxVDOF6EyRWJHQnjzBwzqzb8ZxRwuT96bXowp0LXJhcmvwTcgMgERnkjH/AaARcAjNxDH5wLDrLDhcz2zcRHb9Lh3u/2zWKw8tGb9MBwIwJIaUQzAR2QimZb0y3ablR6cgZxr/pOQhDBZ6Kw68WmRQBbFTTSDtIgYdQ7tUBM@apnQlqBTvqSRCv1TYJM/CmHqQrkd4klmWRSLFVQ81sxp8iiL@eUboaL55EOs0ojko38/REo6YzffahttMHWnX6hLbTdNi2A1ezz/6hnMhIapnKTF40yBLipuWoXVqu2vF8wYG3pIfhBakcm9VUKToklYBzpdVSrTFAAtk/)

Anonymous code block that takes input curried, like `f(a,b)(s)`.

I'm pretty sure this matches up with the intent of the question. Basically, it only makes the substitution if the position of `a` is not within any of the *overlapping* matches of `b`.

Comment: however in tests there's 2p : in `pEpmpptpyp` instead of `pEpmptpyp`

Comment: @Nahuel Fixed. This should also handle the other test cases (and I think is the first to do so)

Comment: @JoKing Unfortunately after rethinking some of the test cases pointed out, I think the last test case will fail [`1222`, `22`, `122`] -> `12122`. I have updated the question to clarify and apologize that I hadn't made this corner case more clear earlier.

Comment: i had a similar issue with `s/(?!$b)$a/$b/g`, when $a is empty because empty string after `p` was matching `(?!p)` i needed `(?<!p)(?!p)`

Comment: @Quinn Fixed I think?

Comment: @JoKing It seems fixed to me!

Comment: Seems to fail if `b` is the empty string

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 55 bytes

```
≔⁰εＦ⌕ＡθηＦ‹‹ιε⬤⌕Ａθζ∨‹ικ›⁺ιＬη⁺κＬζ«≔⁺⁺ω✂θει¹ζω≔⁺ιＬηε»⁺ω✂θε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BCsIwEEXX5hSzTCCCddtVN7optOAJQh3b0JBiUi1UPHucpFJUHMKQfN78P2k65ZpBmRAK73Vr@U4CipxdBgf8oO25MIZfJXRCQNJK9H5pOpISIvABziRVbiV6eh4dqhEdr80taSXaduw4WUpIWr9qs1gKHmzzXigRqU0STkY3GGNQAjll0SImTrTy18BPTPzSk9VO2/GPFwXmIWR7KkaHLmF7Ny8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰ε
```

Initialise a variable to show where the last replaced match ended.

```
Ｆ⌕Ａθη
```

Find all overlapping matches of `a` in `S`.

```
Ｆ‹‹ιε
```

If the next match does not overlap the last successful replacement...

```
⬤⌕Ａθζ∨‹ικ›⁺ιＬη⁺κＬζ«
```

... and it also overlaps no copy of `b` in `S`...

```
≔⁺⁺ω✂θει¹ζω
```

... then concatenate the intermediate substring between the last match and this match with `b` to the output string...

```
≔⁺ιＬηε
```

... and update the last match end variable to the end of this new match.

```
»⁺ω✂θε
```

At the end, add on any remainder of `S` and output the result.

Comment: @tsh OK this is a complete rewrite, I hope this now covers all possible cases...

Comment: @Neil I believe this is also valid !

Comment: @Neil I believe this is valid now.

Comment: @Quinn Ooh, does that make me first to make their answer valid? Neat!

Comment: @Neil I believe JoKing also has a valid answer

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>43</s> <s>122</s> <s>96</s> 88 bytes

```
##2~StringReplacePart~Cases[#2~P~#,{a_,b_}/;And@@(#2<b||#>a&@@@P@##2)]&
P=StringPosition
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Ra4MwFIXf/RVZAt0GmcP4uLVkjMHelm0PPhQpN206BTWiKaVY/esuMfallHDOTb6Te@GWYDJVgsm3MO6XIyFs@DVNXv39qLqArRLQmOEdWtWubSQGQjvYULnpn1/eqh3nD4S9yvOZrGDBORfcDnhMF4FY@ilCt7nJdTV@H3JluLDMrDtC@qfV3g6khJI4TV1rF3QYQEoATPFsUuKeWv6pikKjRDfF7s4G2gpV2meJPlKkM3R0tVVNrg9tcULJV4JMBua@DcPQhZgiPBebUd/8Udbm5JBTfYPJKyYna67oXPx7iiIWI4dY7Dxinvr9wCHvQly@u2PXipxYdKHMscnsHfdBP/4D)

+79: should be fixed.

Call as `f[a,S,b]`.

```
                                                                      & (* a function which finds *)
                            #2~P~#,                                     (* the positions {start,end} where a occurs in S *)
                      Cases[       {a_,b_}/;And@@(#2<b||#>a&@@@     )]  (* which are not a subrange of any of the *)
                                                               P@##2    (* positions of b in S, *)
##2~StringReplacePart~                                                  (* and replaces those parts of the string with b *)
P=StringPosition
```

Comment: Fails for 121212, 1, 121 - should output 121212

Comment: @attinat Seems fixed to me!

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 (`-lpF/;/`), 41 bytes

```
($_,$a,$b)=@F;s/(?<!(?=$b).)(?!$b)$a/$b/g
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##NY7BCsIwEETv@YoUArZQG5riaS31onjTW4@SxWILsRuaivjzxqRUdpZ5u3MZ201m530qbrnQucCsPpzAybTZJ2lTh7vI0iYJLrQUKB/el0opCArOtEbUGhYhsnNnDPGWJnNPgICPxFp655x6/o7uummglzMf3l5aPvd63riiKGIIccM3Z8ennT8A9g@4AgJOK8ZdiJWq4qCqUGbtspS5XkMQB8qQlF@y80Cj81tjTxLkDw)

Comment: [`1222`, `22`, `122`] should output `12122`, but yours outputs `11222`

Comment: ok didn't understand that, maybe fixed, and shorter

Comment: Oh no actually the last test case has one too many `12`s, turns out the question I made was much harder than I originally thought!

Comment: @Quinn, it seems to me that it's not consistent : `123`,`23`,`12` -> `112` but `1212`,`1`,`121`->`1212` (? why it shouldn't be `121212`)

Comment: it seems to be what should be clarified is which positions in `S` should not match with `b` or which part to skip before looking for next match

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's inconsistent. `123,23,12 -> 112` is because in this case `a` is `23` and `b` is `12`, `23` is not wholly part of `12` (there are parts of `a`. that are not in `b`). `1212,1,121->1212` because `a` is `1` and b is `121` so each instance of `a` is fully contained in an instance of `b`. I hope that clears it up a bit.